# Is the natural map composited by direct image functor and inverse image functor a natural isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Assume $\pi: \mathrm{X}\to \mathrm{Y}$ is a continuous map of topological space, then for sheaves respectively on them, the direct image functor is defined as: $\pi_*\mathscr{F}(\mathrm{V})=\mathscr{F}(\pi^{-1}(\mathrm{V}))$ for $\mathrm{V}\subset\mathrm{Y}$; The inverse image functor is defined as: $\pi^{-1}\mathscr{G}(\mathrm{U})=(\underrightarrow{\lim}_{\mathrm{V}\supset\pi(\mathrm{U})}\mathscr{G}(\mathrm{V}))^{\mathrm{sh}}$ for $\mathrm{U}\subset\mathrm{X}$. The two functors are adjoint ($\pi^{-1}$ is left-adjoint, $\pi_*$ is right-adjoint).

Now question is: whether the unit $\epsilon: \pi^{-1}\pi_*\to\mathrm{id}$ is natural isomorphism or not?

---

The question comes from the book The Rising Sea: Foundations of Algebraic Geometry, page 92 and page 136.

Page 92:

> Note that we then get canonical maps $\pi^{-1}\pi_*\mathscr{F}\to\mathscr{F}$ (associated to the identity in $\mathrm{Mor_Y}(\pi_*\mathscr{F},\pi_*\mathscr{F})$) and $\mathscr{G}\to\pi_*\pi^{-1}\mathscr{G}$ (associated to the identity in $\mathrm{Mor_X}(\pi^{-1}\mathscr{F},\pi^{-1}\mathscr{F})$).

I didn't know what this means, so I skipped. But later I met the other sentence (Page 136):

> ...more precisely, is an isomorphism $\mathscr{O}_\mathrm{Y}\to \pi_*\mathscr{O}_\mathrm{X}$ of sheaves on $\mathrm{Y}$, or equivalently by adjointness, $ \pi^{-1}\mathscr{O}_\mathrm{Y}\to\mathscr{O}_\mathrm{X}$ of sheaves on $\mathrm{X}$.

Why here says "equivalently"? Is the latter map the composition $\pi^{-1}\mathscr{O}_\mathrm{Y}\to\pi^{-1}\pi_*\mathscr{O}_\mathrm{X}\to\mathscr{O}_\mathrm{X}$ of sheaves on $\mathrm{X}$? If the former is an isomorphism is equivalent to the latter is, whether this means that $\pi^{-1}\pi_*\mathscr{O}_\mathrm{X}\to\mathscr{O}_\mathrm{X}$ is an isomorphism? Associated with the sentence I didn't understand on page 92 showed above, then I come up with the question (I guess maybe that sentence can help, so I show it here).

If the answer is not, then what the author really means here?

Thank you for helping me!

---

Through the example given by the first comment, I thought of a further question, which is also more closer to the context of the book:

If the map $\pi$ is a homeomorphism, then whether the unit $\epsilon: \pi^{-1}\pi_*\to\mathrm{id}$ is natural isomorphism or not?

---

The last question's answer is Yes, as the second comment said. Now my doubts about this are all solved. Thanks again for helping me!

Comment: Answer to the title question: no. For example, let $Y = 1$.

Comment: Answer to the new question: yes, of course. $\pi_*$ and $\pi^{-1}$ are mutually adjoint equivalences in that case, since the definition of a sheaf on $X$ visibly uses no information other than the structure of the lattice of open sets of $X,$ which is what a homemorphism respects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two comments have solved the question, so I summarize here, for that the question **won't be still marked as "Unanswered"**.

For the first question: let $\mathrm{Y}=1$, hence $\pi^{-1}\pi_*\mathscr{F}(\mathrm{U})=\mathrm{X}$ for all $\mathrm{U}\subset\mathrm{X}$, which is certainly wrong for general situations.

For the second question: Just note that homeomorphism ensure that $\pi^{-1}\mathscr{F}(\mathrm{U})=\mathscr(\pi(\mathrm{U}))$. The essence is as the second comment said.